# Rails ActionController unknown format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller, axlsx

I am trying to render a `xlsx` file.  But I keep getting a `406/UnknowFormat`.  I have done the right setup, maybe im missing something?

Rails 4.2 app

```
gem 'axlsx'
gem "axlsx_rails"
gem 'zip-zip'
```

config/initializers/mime

`Mime::Type.register "application/xlsx", :xlsx`

controller

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx { render xlsx: "create", template: "api/reports/create" }
end
```

views/api/reports/create.xlsx.axlsx

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Reports") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row [@report_name]
end
```

Comment: try this `format.xlsx { render xlsx: "create", filename: "api/reports/create.xlsx" }`

Comment: Nope still got 

`Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 10038ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/api/reports_controller.rb:12:in 'create'`

Comment: Try restarting your server.

Comment: that was the first thing I had done lol

Comment: Have you tried setting the name via header? https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails#file-name

Comment: Im not sure thats relevant to the issue.  For some reason ActionController is not able to find the xlsx format, that would be for sneding the file or downloading it, its not even getting to that point :(

Comment: For what it is worth, `axlsx_rails` defines the xlsx mime type. You shouldn't have to.

Comment: Couple of quick questions: - 1. Could you please post the view code that hits that route please. 2. why do you have axlsx and axlsx_rails in your gemfile? axlsx is a dependency of axlsx_rails, so just axlsx_rails should be sufficient if I understand what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you are getting doesn't mean that rails didn't find the the xlsx format: it means that it compared the list of formats you're providing (i.e. just xlsx) and compared it to the set of formats it thinks the browser is willing to accept and didn't find any overlap.

If as it appears there is only one format you want to render then you don't need to use `respond_to` at all - just replace the whole thing with

```
render xlsx: "create", template: "api/reports/create"
```

Rails derives what it thinks are acceptable formats from the extension on the url and the Accept header. Format negotiation is generally simply done via the extension than the Accept header - linking (or posting) to `/some/path.xlsx` should set the format to xlsx. You can do this by including `format: 'xlsx'` in the options you pass to path helpers or as part of a hash of routing options.

Comment: `axlsx_rails` used to add `xlsx` to the available formats array if it was missing. This would allow you to serve `xlsx` even if the url didn't have the right extension. This became very troublesome with Rails 4 and it was removed. So the problem with `respond_to` probably comes from not having the `xlsx` extension in the requesting url.

Answer (score 11):

For me, in Rails 4.2 I had to specify the full template filename including extension.  According to the [axlsx_rails docs](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails#troubleshooting) the syntax is different in Rails 4.2.  Here's what worked for me:

*some_controller.rb*

```
def create_report
  render "template_path/report.xlsx.axlsx"
end
```

*template_path/report.xlsx.axlsx*

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Basic Worksheet") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ["First Column", "Second", "Third"]
end
```

Comment: For Rails 4.2, I got away with just typing in the file extension ... `render xlsx: 'report_evals_by_supvr.xlsx.axlsx'` or `render 'report_evals_by_supvr.xlsx.axlsx'` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Well I am really late here, and the OP has probably moved on, but for others who've happened onto this problem, a possible explanation might be forgetting to set the format in the link itself. For example, you'd need to do something like this in your view: `download_file_path(format: "xlsx")`

Comment: This was the issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have `format.xlsx` present in your controller, then adding `format.html` might be the solution if you are rendering a page and your `xlsx` file is a link.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xlsx { ... }
end
```